# How do I get floating divs to break directly to the left of the viewport?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Please see example below, and slowly shrink your viewport width.

As the viewport width shrinks, I want the 4th div to go directly under the first div, and then as it shrinks more, i want the 3rd div under the 1st, and the 4th under the 2nd.  I understand why this is happening, I just don't know what to do to get the behaviour I want.

Please help!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

.columnClass
{
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="columnClass">
    <img src="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png" width="400" height="400"/>
</div>

<div class="columnClass">
    <img src="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png" width="200" height="600"/>
</div>

<div class="columnClass">
    <img src="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png" width="400" height="400"/>
</div>

<div class="columnClass">
    <img src="http://thecybershadow.net/misc/stackoverflow.png" width="200" height="600"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is it doing now?

Comment: What you probably need to do is put all of those divs in a wrapper div and set its width to 100%.

Comment: Right now, the 4th div gets stuck under the 3rd one. I want them to wrap directly to the left edge, but it seems that's not how float works.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the point where the 4th one gets stuck under the 3rd one, and there's a big blank space under the 1st and 2nd one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your class parameters to those:

```
.columnClass
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N7usG/
Here I've reduced the width of the images to see it working.

Comment: Ah, this is what i wanted.  Thx!   I know DiMono said it's not possible, but any chance the 4th div it can tuck itself way up so that it touches the 1st div?

Comment: Nope, there is no way. Maybe you should try jquery.masonry library.  http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: oh! definitely gonna try masonry out!

Answer (score 0):

Elements with float: left; will float left as high as possible until they hit something. In your case, you have pictures of alternating length. When the top left corner of the 4th one hits the bottom right corner of the 2nd one, that's where it stops. What you can do instead is this:

```
<style>
.columnClass {
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

This should give the containers a constant height, so that they float the way you want them to.

Comment: This won't work because the content of each div will be entered by a user into a CMS, and I need to account for whatever width and height the divs end up being.

Comment: Fact remains, as long as you have elements of different height they will collide with each other when floating. If you don't want to set it in css, you need to do it with javascript by finding the largest height value in the group and setting all of them to have that as a height value.

Comment: Gotcha.  I understand the javascript solution.  However, is there no way to get that 4th div to wrap all the way to the left, and all the way up, tightly underneath the 1st div?   If I use javascript to increase their height to the largest, then i just create extra white space.

Comment: Tightly to the bottom of the one on the left? Nope.